# Saving directory list to text file

Tags: windows, backup

I found out I need to use `dir /s > filelist.txt` to lookup a directory list, what I need is to rename the file to `filelist/currentdate.txt`, how do I do that?

EDIT: Guess I should have looked a bit more...
Including `%date%` and possibly `%time%` names the file with the current date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, %DATE% won't work in this case directly -

```
rename filelist.txt %date%.txt
```

The above line would give you an error.

The way to go about this is -

```
set MTH=%DATE:~4,2%
set DAY=%DATE:~7,2%
set YR=%DATE:~10,4%
echo %YR% %MTH% %DAY%
```

The above lines basically cut up the %DATE% environment variable into little pieces, which can then be used.

So you type in or copy-paste the lines above. Then you just enter -

```
dir /s > filelist.txt
ren filelist.txt filelist-%YR%-%MTH%-%DAY%.txt
```

This would give you, for example, filelist-2011-02-04.txt.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The error is because of the slashes in the date. Note that using `%DATE%` (even carving it up using substrings) is not portable since the format is localized).

Answer (score 1):

Rename the file to its new name. Make the directory. Move and rename the file to its new location.

```
rename filelist.txt currentdate.txt
md filelist
move currentdate.txt filelist
```